# Asterisk configuration for voicemail emails through GMail SMTP server not working

Tags: asterisk, pbx

I am trying to configure Asterisk (running on AstLinux) to send emails when it receives voicemails through GMail's SMTP server, but it is not working. I do not receive any emails, and I get the following error in the Asterisk system log:

> Dec 14 02:02:56 donald mail.info msmtpqueue: Mail system is stopped. Use 'msmtpqueue' to display the mail queue.

These are my configuration files (my server is located at donald.example.com)

**rc.conf**

```
## SMTP Mail Relay
## This is the SMTP server that all mail from cron, etc. on this
## system will be sent through.  This includes Asterisk VM notifications.
SMTP_SERVER="smtp.gmail.com"
## SMTP_DOMAIN
SMTP_DOMAIN="donald.example.com"
SMTP_HOSTNAME="pbx"
SMTP_TLS=yes
SMTP_STARTTLS=on
SMTP_CERTCHECK=off
## The username and password for communicating with the SMTP server.
SMTP_USER="example@gmail.com"
SMTP_PASS="plaintext_password"
SMTP_AUTH=plain
SMTP_PORT=587
```

**Voicemail.conf**

```
[default]
1111 => 1234,Nick,myemail@example.com,,tz=eastern|attach=yes|serveremail=noreply@server.com|format=wav
```

Comment: What is `msmtpqueue` output? Do you have any other mail related messages in the logfile?

Comment: `msmtpqueue` outputs the formulated email queue, but nothing else. There are no other messages related to emails in the log file.

Comment: Try to manually flush the queue: `msmtpqueue -f`

Comment: Please accept your own answer so that people know your problem has been solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the web interface of Asterisk, I had to modify the SMTP settings in the Network tab, instead of editing the rc.conf configuration file. Once I made the changes under "Outbound SMTP Mail Relay" on the Network tab and rebooted the machine, Asterisk cleared the message queue and pushed all of the queued emails out.